# Compare data between MongoDB and MySQL using python script

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, pymongo, pymysql

I am working on a Django Application that uses both MySQL and MongoDB to store its data. What I need to do is to compare the data that are stored in the MongoDB's collection and stored in the MySQL's table.

For example, my MySQL database contains the table "relation", which is created using:

```
CREATE TABLE relations (service_id int, beneficiary_id int, PRIMARY KEY (service_id, beneficiary_id));
```

My MongoDB contains a collection called "relation", which is expected to store the same data as the relation table in MySQL. The following is one document of the collection "relation":

```
{'_id': 0, 'service_id': 1, 'beneficiary_id': 32}
```

I tried to create a python script that compares the data between the relation table in MySQL and relation collection in Mongo. The script works as the following:

```
mysql_relations = Relations.objects.values('beneficiary_id', 'service_id')
mongo_relations_not_in_mysql = relations_mongodb.find({'$nor':list(mysql_relations)})

mongo_relations = relations_mongodb.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'beneficiary_id':1, 'service_id': 1})
filter_list = Q()
for mongo_relation in mongo_relations:
    filter_list &= Q(mongo_relation)
mysql_relations_not_in_mongo = Relations.objects.exclude(filter_list)
```

However, this code takes forever.
I think the main problem is because of the primary key that is composed of 2 columns, which required the usage of the Q() and the '$nor'.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is interested, I used the following solution to optimize the data comparison.

(The Idea was to create a temporary MySQL Table to store mongo's data, then doing the comparison between the the MySQL tables). The code is below:

1. Get the relations From MongoDB

   ```
   mongo_relations = relations_mongodb.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'service_id': 1, 'beneficiary_id': 1})
   ```
2. Create a temporary MySQL table to store MongoDB'S relations

   ```
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute(
       "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_relations (service_id int, beneficiary_id int, INDEX `id_related` (`service_id`, `beneficiary_id`) );"
   )
   ```
3. Insert MongoDB's relations not the temporary table just created

   ```
   cursor.executemany(
       'INSERT INTO temp_relations (service_id, beneficiary_id) values (%(service_id)s, %(beneficiary_id)s) ',
           list(mongo_relations)
   )
   ```
4. Get the MongoDB's relations that does not exist in MySQL

   ```
   cursor.execute(
       "SELECT service_id, beneficiary_id FROM temp_relations WHERE (service_id, beneficiary_id) NOT IN ("
           "SELECT service_id, beneficiary_id FROM relations);"
   )
   mongo_relations_not_in_mysql = cursor.fetchall()
   ```
5. Get MySQL relations that does not exist in MongoDB

   ```
   cursor.execute(
       "SELECT id, service_id, beneficiary_id, date FROM relations WHERE (service_id, beneficiary_id) not IN ("
           "SELECT service_id, beneficiary_id FROM temp_relations);"
   )
   mysql_relations_not_in_mongo = cursor.fetchall()
   cursor.close()   # Close the connection to MySQL
   ```